# python selenium open InternetExplorer with ActiveX

Tags: python, selenium

Code Trial 1:

```
driver1 = webdriver.Ie()
driver1.get(url1)
code1 = login(driver)
```

Code Trial 2:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver2.get(url2)
code2 = login(url2)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Welcome Huanyang Guo! Please read and follow the guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's important so that people can help you. You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: @huanyangguo I have formatted the verbatim of your question. Please review and let me know if that looks good and is as per your actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for basic steps to open IE using selenium in python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Ie("YOUR_PATH_TO_EXE_FILE")

driver.close()
```